# How to import array from text file as the same format of numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a text file which contains a multi dimensional array as:

```
1  2  3
1  2  3
1  2  3
1  2  3.
```

When I am importing the text file with `np.loadtxt`. I am getting the format of the array as:

```
[[1.0  2.0  3.0]
 [1.0  2.0  3.0]
 [1.0  2.0  3.0]
 [1.0  2.0  3.0]]
```

but I want to have the following format:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
```

How can I do so?

Comment: I really doubt that is what you get when using `np.loadtxt`, as it should simply give you exactly what you want. You know that printing an array removes all commas?

Comment: Are you by any chance printing the array? Print usually removes this comma. But, if you inspect the array that is returned then, it should indeed be a valid ndarrray

Comment: BTW why do you care about what format the array is printed? You need to use a different type of print to achieve that, check my anser below @BideshSengupta

Answer (score 0):

Just use `repr` while printing the numpy array, which will keep all commas intact, normal `print` removes all commas! Or you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint

```
import numpy as np
import pprint
arr = np.loadtxt('file.json')
print(arr)
#[[1. 2. 3.]
# [1. 2. 3.]
# [1. 2. 3.]
# [1. 2. 3.]]
print(repr(arr))
#array([[1., 2., 3.],
#       [1., 2., 3.],
#       [1., 2., 3.],
#       [1., 2., 3.]])
pprint.pprint(arr)
#array([[1., 2., 3.],
#       [1., 2., 3.],
#       [1., 2., 3.],
#       [1., 2., 3.]])
```